# Cannot resolve symbol "LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container"

Tags: java, android

I have a method "displayEventInvitationList" that have parameters "inflater,container" when i am call that method like "displayEventInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container)" in  "onoptionsitemselected" i am getting error cannot resolve symbol "inflater,container".Please suggest me the code how to solve that problem.

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "yes");

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.all:
                //I am getting "cannot resolve symbol" here  
                displayEventInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container); 
                return true;
            case R.id.event:
                displayEventList();
                return true;
            case R.id.invitation:
                displayInvitationList();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }
public View displayEventInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventForUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                List<EventMO> groupEventInvitesList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                    groupEventInvitesList.add(eventMO);

                }
                for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                    groupEventInvitesList.add(eventMO);

                }

                return groupEventInvitesList;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventInvitesList) {
                groupEventMoList = groupEventInvitesList;
                chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                groupEventView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You have to pass those two parameters.

Comment: i am getting error while passing those two parameters in onoptionsitemselected .

Comment: You have to create objects and pass it.  Then you wont get errors.

Comment: @pselvasimon You aren't passing any arguments. You should research the difference between a "Method Call" and a "Method Declaration". The former takes "arguments", the latter "parameters".

Comment: can you please tell where i am create object?

Comment: where would you going to add the view? on your layout?

Comment: @arun can please explain briefly where i am create object and pass it.

Comment: @pselvasimon you can create inflater like LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: yes i have that layoutinflater in my adapter functionality..then

Comment: where you want to display this view?? we cant understand your problem. describe more.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my comment, the problem is that you are not providing any arguments to your method call:

```
displayEventInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container);
```

If you are extending `Fragment` to create this class, then one option would be to store the `LayoutInflater` and `ViewGroup` arguments from `onCreateView`. You could save these to class variables and use them in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

```
//Class Variables
LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewGroup container;
//...
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.container = container;
}

//And in onOptionsItemSelected...
displayEventInvitationList(inflater, container);
```

Failing that, you will need to find a way to access an appropriate `LayoutInflater` and `ViewGroup` object to use as arguments. `LayoutInflater` is relatively straight forward (i.e.  `LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);`) , but you will need to access the correct `ViewGroup` for any layouts and widgets to render.

Also, the way you structured your method call implies you do not understand Java basics when it comes to method calls/declarations, which is really essential understand Android. So, I would also recommend you take some time to familiarise yourself with them.